# ImageView.setImageBitmap not displaying image in RecyclerView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am displaying an image in a `RecyclerView` whose source is is a bitmap taken from an MMS message.  The problem is that the image is not displaying.  Absolutely nothing is displayed.  Here is my onBindView:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    final String name = mDataset.get(position).getContact() ;
    final MMSMessage message = mDataset.get(position);
    holder.txtHeader.setText(name);
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(message.getDate());
    holder.txtDate.setText(dateTime.toString(Globals.generalSQLFormatterDT));
    holder.txtText.setText(message.getBody());
    holder.txtText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Bitmap bitmap = message.getBitmap();
    if (bitmap != null) {
        //bitmap is not null and I can see an image using Android Studio
        bitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false); 
        holder.imgMMS.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } else {
        holder.imgMMS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

The xml for the ImageView:

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_below="@+id/thirdLine"
    android:id="@+id/imageMMS"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
     />
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673366/bitmap-image-not-displayed-in-imageview) and tried to scale down the image to an arbitrary small size.  I don't think it's an out of memory error - I tried putting in the launcher icon as a test.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why in `if` there is no action opossite to `else` ?

Comment: @Selvin not sure what you mean?

Comment: there is only one "action" in on `else` ... where is opossite action in `if` ... I would like to get penny for every similar question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (bitmap != null) {
        //bitmap is not null and I can see an image using Android Studio
        bitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false); 
        holder.imgMMS.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
holder.imgMMS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.imgMMS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

You are setting visibility to GONE. My guess is that the RecyclerView is recycling the views, and when it does the view is GONE since you are not setting it to Visible. Try adding holder.imgMMS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); for when bitmap is not null, like so:

```
if (bitmap != null) {
        //bitmap is not null and I can see an image using Android Studio
        bitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false); 
        holder.imgMMS.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        holder.imgMMS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.imgMMS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```